# Clone month/year select list jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to implement a custom layout for jquery-ui datepicker which includes a single month/year select list at the top:

[image: image of desired layout]

I've set `changeMonth` and `changeYear` to `true` so enabled a drop down for the first month, and positioned it in the centre to match my layout:

[image: HTML version]

What i'm trying to do now is `clone` the month & year drop downs into plain text so that they sit on top of the 'January' calendar similar to how 'February 2014' is appearing.

can someone help explain to me how to do this? i've been looking at the API for a long time and there doesn't seem to be a way to add calendar headers - the default style is just to enable them to be select drop downs or plain spans.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you've got so far...

Comment: @LeeTaylor  it's tangled up in a local Grunt+Sass environment with a bunch of dependancies, so difficult to post everything in a Fiddle. I'm working on that now but in the meantime you can see my Javascript in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmackay/zHBpL/ Please excuse my procedural hacking.